# I am inside my router settings but I don't know whats the password

Tags: wireless-router, password-recovery

Ok I am in the router settings but I don't know the password for it but I can change it but I need the old password so is there a way to find the router settings password inside the router settings password because sometimes I have to access it another computer.

Here is the router name TP-LINK Wireless Network WR340G/WR340GD

EDIT: I edited the post so you can understand it more. I sometimes get very confused so I make mistakes

EDIT 2: Thanks for your tips but I just remembered my password now :) so I changed it now to a easier one

Comment: If you forgot the pass you will have to reset the router.  There is normally a button on the bottom of the device that does this.

Comment: Are you saying you can login from another machine? Does this machine have the password saved in the web browser? If not, what does the other computer have to do with not knowing a password for a router?

Answer (score 5):

If you can access the management utility from a certain computer, you should go to that computer to change the password to one you can remember. It may or may not require you to enter the current password.

Otherwise, if you can not access the router from any computer because you don't have a password, you will need to reset the router to factory default. **This will lose all your setting and you will have to setup the router again.**

Here are instructions how to reset your router: [How to reset TP-LINK products with WPS/RESET button to factory defaults](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/article/?faqid=497).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you can access the router settings on one computer without logging in to the router there, then your password is probably remembered in the browser password storage or cookies. It may be possible to retrieve it from there.

If not, and you decide to reset your router to factory defaults using the method described by [CharlieRB](https://superuser.com/a/722831) or others, then be sure to use the computer where you do have access and write down (or print-out) all your settings first, so after you reset the router to the factory settings, you can restore any settings you have changed.

Comment: Note, if they're saved in Firefox, you can view the saved passwords in (Firefox menu) → Preferences → Preferences → (Security tab) → Saved Passwords… → Show Passwords.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't remember your password you will need to reset your router back to factory default. You can do this either from within the router settings or most routers have a reset button on them somewhere.

As you can imagine they aren't going to leave your password lying around in plain text anywhere, so reset is your only option.

I suggest you look into a password manager application to avoid this problem again. [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) will do you, but lots more out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have forgotten the password, there is no other way than restoring the router to the factory settings.

---

**If your're inside admin panel:**

[image]

**If you're NOT inside admin panel:**

[image]
[image]

Press following button(s) for longer than 10 seconds.